# Need help creating a query to extract values from a single column and arrange them into individual columns in Oracle PL/SQL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing an extract for a feed and the receiving system wants the values from a single column arranged in individual columns.

Here is how the data is stored:

| Person ID | Hobbies |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Gardening |
| 123 | Hiking |
| 176 | Reading |
| 366 | Hiking |
| 366 | Gardening |
| 366 | Football |

And here is what I need the query to produce.  Note that I need this to be in the form of a query that can run every night to extract the feed.  Also note that the hobbies need to be sorted asc so a different value might go into each column for each person, as below:

| Person ID | Hobby 1 | Hobby 2 | Hobby 3 | Hobby 4 | Hobby 5 | Hobby 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Gardening | Hiking |  |  |  |  |
| 176 | Reading |  |  |  |  |  |
| 366 | Football | Gardening | Hiking |  |  |  |

It's like the opposite of listagg and I'm stuck.  Any help would be much appreciated!

I tried sorting the hobbies and returning the first row, but I don't know how to get rows 2-6.

Before everyone jumps on me for asking yet another pivot table question, this is not summing values and the columns are not defined (Gardening y/n, Hiking y/n, etc.) so the pivot table code I've used before isn't working for this case - unless I'm thinking about this the wrong way??

Comment: Why would "Gardening" end up in `Hobby 1` and "Hiking" in `Hobby 2` for ID 123 but not for ID 366?

Comment: what if somebody has more than 6 hobbies? what if it is 10000 hobbies?

Comment: Why Gardening is in Hobby 1 for 123 and in Hobby 2 for 366 is because I need the hobbies sorted alphabetically and for person 366, Football comes before Gardening.  That's the tricky part about this - the columns Hobby1-6 are just buckets for whatever that person has, they are not specific to any particular hobby

Comment: What if more than 6 hobbies?  I know, I argued that, but the receiving system and feed owner agreed that 6 is all they want

Answer (score 3):

I would just derive a row number for each, and then use conditional aggregation.

```
select
  person,
  max(case when rn = 1 then hobby else null end) as hobby1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then hobby else null end) as hobby2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then hobby else null end) as hobby3
from 
(
  select
    person,
    hobby,
    row_number() over (partition by person order by hobby) as rn
  from foo
) t
group by person;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5mjiS6j2)

Comment: Oooh, interesting, testing this approach now.  Question: why the max?

Comment: Ah, the max is there to group by person and have one row per person with all the columns filled in.  Got it.  Thank you, @Andrew, this is cool!  Now, how do I incorporate this into the larger query - this is only 6 of about 25 fields being returned.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Crispy - sadly enough, more columns for this equals more typing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't word that clearly.  This hobby thing is a sub-query - the whole feed is one query, like select name, address, phone, title, department, hobby1, hobby2, hobby3, hobby4, hobby5, hobby6, supervisorID, supervisorname from table1, table2, table3, hobbies, table4 where x,y,z, join join join etc.  So the rownum and group by that enables the hobby columns to be populated correctly -  I need to embed that into the larger query.  I get how to do the rownum subquery but I am stuck on how to do the max and group by in the context of the larger query.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Crispy: Simply join this query to the other tables, E.g. `select * from persons join ( <above query> ) hobbies on hobbies.person = persons.person` or `with ( <above query> ) as hobbies select * from persons join hobbies on hobbies.person = persons.person`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way to do it using `PIVOT` :

```
with cte as (
  select person, hobby,
  row_number() over (partition by person order by hobby) as rn
  from mytable
)
select *
from cte
pivot 
(  max(HOBBY)
   for rn in (1 as "hobby1", 2 as "hobby2", 3 as "hobby3", 4 as "hobby4", 5 as "hobby5", 6 as "hobby6")
)
```

Result :

```
PERSON  hobby1      hobby2     hobby3   hobby4  hobby5  hobby6
123     Gardening   Hiking     null     null    null    null
176     Reading     null       null     null    null    null
345     Football    Gardening  Hiking   null    null    null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/M-9TKY8d)